# Using dropdownlist and actions in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a table where you can see the current state of a person (which is loaded from a database) in MVC3. The user have an option to change and set the status, which is saved to the database. As an example:

[image: Example]

I'm very new to MVC3 and I'm not sure how to take the value of the dropdown menu to the controller.

My code for displaying the dropdownmenu/Set button is as follows:

```
<td>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("Statuses",new SelectList(ViewData.Model.Statuses))%>
    <a href="/People/Set" class="btn btn-primary">Set</a>
</td>
```

I managed to get the Set button to call a method in the "PeopleController," but I'm not sure how to:

1. pass in the value from the dropdownlist
2. ensure i'm not passing in the value from a wrong dropdownlist (in this example there are 3 dropdown lists).
3. I have to ensure that I'm changing the status of the correct person - each person has a unique name, and I can change the correct Status if I know the name of the person.

Note:I'm using MVC3.

Comment: Change the set link to a submit button.  Wrap the ddl and button in a form.  Write a post method in your controller to process the data

Comment: @Forty-Two How can I get the id(name) of the person? the id is displayed on the same row as such: ID | Status| Change Status To

Comment: You can put a hidden field with the id in the form as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize and clarify my comments above, Wrap the dropdownlist in a form, make the Set link a submint button, and add a hidden element to pass the Id along as well.

```
    <td>
        <% using(Html.BeginForm())
        {%>
           <%=Html.DropDownList("Statuses",new SelectList(ViewData.Model.Statuses))%>
           <%=Html.Hidden("Id")
           <input type="submit" value="Set" />
        <%}%>
    </td>
```

(ps, consider making the leap to the razor view engine, it's much nicer to read and write)